# Generate a list from list of dicts if value not exists in another list

Tags: python, dictionary

im triying to filter a list of dicts using the elements of a list

```
a=[{"item_id": "ITEM2090", "seller_id":1009954},
   {"item_id": "ITEM2050", "seller_id":1009920},
   {"item_id": "ITEM2032", "seller_id":1009960},
   {"item_id": "ITEM2080", "seller_id":1009954}]

b=["ITEM2032","ITEM2060","ITEM2070","ITEM2090"]
```

expected result (the two dict from list a wich values for item_id not exists in list b):

```
c=[{"item_id": "ITEM2050", "seller_id":1009920},       
   {"item_id": "ITEM2080", "seller_id":1009954}]
```

I've tried:

```
c=[x["item_id"] for x in a if x["item_id"] not in b]
```

My problem is that it returns a list of the `item_id` values, not a list of dicts as I would like.

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do this?

Comment: What have you tried ? Could you post your code ?

Comment: ive tried this , but only returns me the value :

c=[x["item_id"] for x in a if x["item_id"] not in b]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c = [item for item in a if item["item_id"] not in b]
```

Will be better to make "b" as a set in case of a large amount of items.